# RoR v2.3 custom form error handler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering how to output errors from the model a custom way I don't want to change just the message of the error but also how the error looks when its outputted. Currently i'm using this in my view `<%= f.error_messages %>`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the formtastic gem for the easiest and most powerful form customization.

Or you could subclass ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder as described in the Advanced Rails Recipes book, though that is more work and arguably not as clean.

If you are simply looking for a way to modify ActiveRecord's error_messages method, 
you could simply modify them directly in your views:

```
<% object.errors.each do |attr,message| %>
    some html here
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. This will help me a lot.